# Problems validating in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

i'm getting an error message on IE8....all other browsers seem to be fine...i've narrowed it down to specific parts of my JavaScript however i cant find a way around it. It seems to be the greater then or less then signs(i could be wrong). Anyone know a way around it(maybe another way of written the sign, writing and gt; wont do it)

example code:

```
var selectedDate = new Date(document.getElementById("ExpYear").value,document.getElementById("ExpMonth").value)
var nextmonth = selectedDate.setMonth(selectedDate.getMonth());
var last_date_of_selected_date = new Date(nextmonth -1);
var today = new Date();
today = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth());

if (today > selectedDate) {<!--i think its the < sign-->
   return false;
}
else {
    return true;
}


window.onload = function() {
    var a = document.getElementById("PaymentForm");
    a.onsubmit = function() { return Validate() };
}
```

Comment: What does the error message say? What value does `today` have? What value does `selectedDate` have? Wouldn't `return (today > selectedDate)` be neater then having a big if/else?

Comment: @David Dorward: error just says expected ')' on line 105 which is the if(today > selectedDate) line. ill add the whole function.

Comment: Just one side mark: you know that HTML comments are not allowed within script blocks, don't you? Use either `//` or `/* comment */` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var selectedDate = new Date (document.getElementById("ExpYear").value,document.getElementById("ExpMonth").value)
```

I'm not sure if this solves your issue, but there are at least three problems with this line of code:

1. the [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor expects either zero arguments, one argument containing a timestamp in milliseconds or a string (discouraged) *or* **three arguments** containing year, month and day number respectively (possibly followed by four arguments containing hour, minute, second, millisecond)
2. the month parameter starts at `0` for January, so you probably should decrement the input value (unless you expect the user to enter a number in the range 0 – 11).
3. a semicolon is missing; though JavaScript interpreters have something called automatic semicolon insertion, it's likely you write better code using semicolons everywhere.

**Update:** in your second piece of code, the message about `a` being `null` or not an object is probably because there's no element with ID `PaymentForm`, so the line trying to attach an event handler to `a` will yield an error.

Moreover, you omitted a semicolon after the closing brace (and you probably forgot a closing brace *and* semicolon after `return Validate();`).

Comment: thanks for the help...the comments were just put in the function at the end to point out where the prob may be, however i was testing the script on my xslt page...i now put it back in its own file and the prob may have gone away...i think my problem lies with the window.onload on the page.

Comment: @Hatzi: how should we know if that's the case? You didn't show us your `window.onload` function.

Comment: error says 'null' is null or not an object; ill post it above

Answer (score 0):

I see you're missing a semicolon on the selectedDate variable declaration.
Internet Explorer is extremely picky with semicolons.

```
var selectedDate = new Date (document.getElementById("ExpYear").value,document.getElementById("ExpMonth").value)
```